# Get all tagged text under li tags

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have list like:

```
<ul>
<li><strong>Text 1</strong></li>
<li>Text 2</li>
<li>Text 3</li>
<li><strong>Text 4</strong></li>
</ul>
```

How i can get only values under strong tag using selenium webdriver in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the data is always in the presented form, a simple regex will do:

```
import re
re.findall(r'<li><strong>([^<]*)</strong></li>', my_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

This simplest way using Webdriver, which is what I'm assuming you're wanting due to your tags is:

```
list = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul")
elements = list.find_elements_by_xpath("./li/strong")
for element in elements:
    print element.text
```

EDIT: Edited for better answer

Comment: it gets only 1 element, also, you cannot use for element for webelement object.

Comment: The variable element is only there for you to understand what was being assigned, it wasn't for you to copy-paste directly. I'm surprised that it only found one element - what is being stated there is "find the list, and then find all elements of that list with the xpath...". I use very similar code repeatedly and I've never known it not to work - where any errors thrown at all?

Comment: I didn't used same code, i changed variables to mine, but as 1st answer is working, i stopped trying others, i will try to make this code work when i will finish main parts of program.